# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lambda_21' (type Lambda)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lambda

I'm trying to run code to train custom OCR with keras_ocr
just copying code from: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19dGKong-LraUG3wYlJuPCquemJ13NN8R#scrollTo=27hytnFasGBO

tensorflow 2.15.0
CUDA: 12.1
keras_ocr 0.9.3

Section train recognizer

```
recognition_batch_size = 8
recognizer_basepath = os.path.join(data_dir, f'recognizer_{datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}')
recognition_train_generator, recognition_val_generator, recogntion_test_generator = [
    recognizer.get_batch_generator(
      image_generator=image_generator,
      batch_size=recognition_batch_size,
      lowercase=True
    ) for image_generator in recognition_image_generators
]
recognizer.training_model.fit_generator(
    generator=recognition_train_generator,
    epochs=1000,
    steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(len(background_splits[0]) / recognition_batch_size),
    callbacks=[
      tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(restore_best_weights=True, patience=25),
      tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(f'{recognizer_basepath}.csv', append=True),
      tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=f'{recognizer_basepath}.h5')
    ],
    validation_data=recognition_val_generator,
    validation_steps=math.ceil(len(background_splits[1]) / recognition_batch_size),
    workers=0
)
```

Generate error message:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lambda_25' (type Lambda).

```
None values not supported.

Call arguments received by layer 'lambda_25' (type Lambda):
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 6), dtype=float32)']
  • mask=None
  • training=True
```

I tried to resize image in batch generator but without success

```
def get_batch_generator(image_generator, batch_size, lowercase):
    for batch in image_generator:
        images, labels = batch
        # Resize images to a fixed size
        images = tf.image.resize(images, [640, 640])  # replace with your desired size
        yield images, labels

recognition_train_generator, recognition_val_generator, recogntion_test_generator = [
    get_batch_generator(
      image_generator=image_generator,
      batch_size=recognition_batch_size,
      lowercase=True,
      
    ) for image_generator in recognition_image_generators
]
```

Without success - Have you got any other ideas?
Thank you in advance

I tried to use fixed size for image

I'm looking for advice how to generate batch for code above without "None" values